# How to check for user idle time in C# and display a message

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, time

I am working on an ASP.NET core web application and I want to get the user idle time. if the user is not working / interacting with the application more than 20 minutes I want to throw a message "User is idle for 20 min".

How do I achieve this?

Comment: yes idle time.. @JamesZ

Comment: if user is idle for 20 min. then we need to throw message

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use javascript solution since we need to track client side user interaction.

ex for 5 seconds user idle.

```
let idletime; 
const resetIdleTime = ()=> {
  console.log('Clearing out the idle time');
  console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
 
  clearTimeout(idletime);
  idletime = setTimeout(trackIdleTime, 5000);
}

const trackIdleTime = ()=> {
  console.log(new Date(Date.now()).toISOString());
  console.log('Do required things when session is idle');
}
resetIdleTime();
document.onmousemove = resetIdleTime;
document.onkeypress = resetIdleTime;
```